# NtAllocateVirtualMemoryEx definition

Tags: winapi, nt-native-api

I am implementing a memory management tool by hooking into memory APIs, when i come to NtAllocateVirtualMemoryEx, i tried to find its definition on google but found nothing, however NtAllocateVirtualMemory is clearly defined at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntallocatevirtualmemory, is there anyone knowing its details?

Comment: The Native API is not a public programming interface. Don't expect to find documentation.

Comment: *ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx* defined in *ntifs.h*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx* defined in *ntifs.h*

```
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN10_RS5)
_Must_inspect_result_
_IRQL_requires_max_(PASSIVE_LEVEL)
_When_(return==0, __drv_allocatesMem(Region))
NTSYSAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx(
    _In_ HANDLE ProcessHandle,
    _Inout_ _At_ (*BaseAddress, _Readable_bytes_ (*RegionSize) _Writable_bytes_ (*RegionSize) _Post_readable_byte_size_ (*RegionSize)) PVOID* BaseAddress,
    _Inout_ PSIZE_T RegionSize,
    _In_ ULONG AllocationType,
    _In_ ULONG PageProtection,
    _Inout_updates_opt_(ExtendedParameterCount) PMEM_EXTENDED_PARAMETER ExtendedParameters,
    _In_ ULONG ExtendedParameterCount
    );
#endif
```

[`MEM_EXTENDED_PARAMETER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-mem_extended_parameter) and all api by fact have the same usage as [`VirtualAlloc2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc2). the [`VirtualAlloc2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc2) is only thin shell over `ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx`

interesting that `VirtualAlloc2` defined in `memoryapi.h` under condition

```
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN10_RS4)
```

but `ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx` declared with condition

```
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN10_RS5)
```

however howminimum one of this condition is mistake - because `VirtualAlloc2` call `ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx` - if `VirtualAlloc2` available -  `ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx` available too.

also was mistake in [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc2):

> - *Library   Kernel32.lib*
> - *DLL   Kernel32.dll*

really `VirtualAlloc2` not exported by *kernel32.dll* and not defined in *kernel32.lib*

need use *mincore.lib* or *mmos.lib* which import this api from [*api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-6.dll*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-apis#apis-from-api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-6dll) (resolved to *kernelbase.dll* now)