# Calling ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx with DllImport

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Im trying to call the low-level function `ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx` instead the typical `VirtualAllocEx`.

Thats an undocumented function from `ntdll.dll`, thats what i found about it:

[NtAllocateVirtualMemoryEx definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64084729/ntallocatevirtualmemoryex-definition)

(`NtAllocateVirtualMemoryEx` and `ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx` are pretty much the same function)

However i dont know which parameters should i put in the `DllImport` export method.
Thats what i tried (not working)

```
[DllImport(NTDLL)]
public static extern uint ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, uint dwSize, uint flAllocationType, uint flProtect, int ExtendedParameters, ulong ExtendedParameterCount);
```

Im pretty sure im missing the correct parameters, but since there is almost no documentation i dont know how to fix the problem.

Comment: `VirtualAlloc2` is documented, why can't you call that?

Comment: I could.. but there isnt a pinvoke documentation.. the parameteres are the same as `ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx`..

Comment: ExtendedParameters is clearly not an int. But do you actually plan to use that parameter? For range-limit or NUMA?

Comment: I dont need to use that parameters, but i must define it in the extern method (DllImport) and i dont know what to put instead int.

Comment: If you don't need it, why use the Ex version of the function at all then?

Comment: Cause i need to allocate the memory of another process

Comment: VirtualAllocEx  can allocate in another process.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, but as said in the question "Im trying to call the low-level function ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx instead the typical VirtualAllocEx." for my project i cant use VirtualAllocEx, i need to use a lower-level api (lower as possibile) and ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx is the lowest.

Comment: Did you see following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff566416(v=vs.85)

Comment: `ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx` is not documented anywhere, I don't think it exists, only `ZwAllocateVirtualMemory` exists. And even if you wanted it, it's a kernel-mode call, so you actually need `NtAllocateVirtualMemory` the documentation is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntallocatevirtualmemory

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64084729/ntallocatevirtualmemoryex-definition @Charlieface

Comment: @jdweng Yes i saw the non-ex version, but since i need to allocate memory in another process i must use the Ex function

Comment: The only difference between the ex and non-ex is the ex methods have extended (more) parameters.  Running in another process doesn't usually doesn't have any thing to do with running in same process or another process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ZwAllocateVirtualMemoryEx` is an undocumented function, and is equivalent to `NtAllocateVirtualMemoryEx`.

You appear to have some incorrect parameter definitions, in particular `uint dwSize` and `int ExtendedParameters` are wrong.

Be that as it may, you should just use the official documented procedures for this. You can use [`VirtualAlloc2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc2), which calls directly to `NtAllocateVirtualMemoryEx`:

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern IntPtr VirtualAlloc2(
  IntPtr Process,
  IntPtr BaseAddress,
  UIntPtr Size,
  int AllocationType,
  int PageProtection,
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 6)]
  MEM_EXTENDED_PARAMETER[] ExtendedParameters = null,
  int ParameterCount
);

struct MEM_EXTENDED_PARAMETER
{
    long Type;
    IntPtr Pointer;
    UIntPtr Size;
    IntPtr Handle;
    int ULong;
}
```

Or you can use the simpler [`VirtualAllocEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualallocex)

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(
  IntPtr hProcess,
  IntPtr lpAddress,
  UIntPtr dwSize,
  uint flAllocationType,
  uint flProtect
);
```

Comment: Zw and Nt are the same in usermode (99% of them are exported as both)